# Fit a vector with linear combination of other vectors with Sklearn (linear regression with a vector as a feature)

Tags: python, vector, scikit-learn, linear-regression

The standard usage of linear regression Sklearn is to pass through an input of size (n_samples, n_features). This format assume each feature is only of 1 dimension.

What I want to do, however, is to fit a linear combination of vectors to another vector. That is, I would like to treat each vector as one feature. I cannot just flatten the feature vectors because this would make an coefficient for each element in a feature vector instead.

Can I realize this in Sklearn?
I can formulate this as an optimization problem in Scipy but I want to do other things like sparse coefficients which has its implementation in Sklearn.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive what you are trying to do is called structured prediction.
Sklearn does not provide this functionality, and according to their [FAQ](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-graphical-models-or-sequence-prediction-to-scikit-learn), they do not plan to develop this.

You can either find a workaround to transform your features and output in scalars, or you can use other projects mentioned by Sklearn:

- [pystruct](https://pystruct.github.io/)
- [seqlearn](https://larsmans.github.io/seqlearn/)